# How to write ruby code in option of image tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, onerror

Today when working with images, I have a problem: when an image is absent or has invalid url (404 or so) I need to replace it with `asset_path("default_avatar.png")`. So I tried:

```
def get_url_avatar url
  return url if url.present? && Faraday.head(url).status == 200
  asset_path "default_avatar.png"
end
```

But then I found other solution - the `onerror` option in `image_tag` to handle the problem on the clientside.
The new code:

```
<%= image_tag (user.avatar),
    class: "avatar",
    onerror: "this.src='asset_path("default_avatar.png")';" %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag (user.avatar),
    class: "avatar",
    onerror: "this.src='<%= asset_path("default_avatar.png") %>';" %>
```

Now I have a new problem with `image_tag`. I need to get value of `asset_path("default_avatar.png")` in `onerror` javascript handler.

But I can't write ruby in `onerror` handler. How to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In erb everything between `<%=` and `%>` is ruby code, so use ruby string interpolation there:

```
<%= image_tag (user.avatar),
    class: "avatar",
    onerror: "this.src='#{asset_path("default_avatar.png")}';" %>
```

Comment: Amazing!! This is solve I've tried but my code wrong

**onerror: 'this.src="#{asset_path("default_avatar.png")}";'**

Comment: result: **<img class="notification-sender-avatar" onerror="this.src=&quot;#{asset_path(&quot;default_avatar.png&quot;)}&quot;;" src="">**

Comment: @phạmtuấn interpolation only works inside double-quotes - `"`